# Never touched this olive tree for 10 years. How to get fruit out of it?

Tags: trees, diagnosis, fruit-trees

I have found this olive tree in my father’s garden absolutely untouched for I believe at least 10 years.

It produces no fruit. Is there any way to save it? I have almost zero experience in gardening so wanted to ask here.

Would appreciate any help
[image]

Comment: A few more pictures would help.

Answer (score 1):

Your olive tree looks very vigorous and healthy so it is in a good location. However the robust health might be one reason why it is not producing fruit. Trees are more useful when they are a bit stressed due to lack of water or nutrient since they are then more apt to produce flowers which then go on to produce fruit.

The growth has apparently produced a lot of intermingling branches, so your first approach will be to prune it according to good horticultural practices. There are lots of articles online describing how to approach this including this [University of California Extension PDF](http://cesonoma.ucanr.edu/files/27277.pdf). You may also find videos which will help you see the principles.

The pruning will result in a lot of active growth that must be controlled, so it will be an ongoing process over a number of years to get it into production. Advanced methods involve heavy pruning and shaping combined with taking of cuttings from the outer growth and grafting them into the remaining branch ends.